# ffmpeg error while adding text on video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, android-ffmpeg

I have used 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2' library for using ffmpeg in my app.I want to add text in video.I have added the library and used the methods specified there .Then I'm passing the ffmpeg command as an argument to the execute method .But it shows an error as output file not specified but i have added an output file in the commands.Don't know what is going wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
 `FFmpeg fFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance (MainActivity.this);
            try {
                fFmpeg.loadBinary (new LoadBinaryResponseHandler () {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        Log.e ("onStart", "onStart load");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure() {
                        Log.e ("onFailure", "onFailure load");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.e ("onSuccess", "onSuccess load");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        Log.e ("onFinish", "onFinish load");
                    }
                });
            } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
                // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
            }

            String[] cmd = {"-y",
                    "-i",
                    "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20171212_120337.mp4",
                    "-vf",
                    "format=yuv444p",
                    "-codec:v",
                    "drawtext=text='Title of this Video': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=(h/PHI)+th  box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5",
                    "-c:v copy",
                    "outVideo.mp4"
            };

            try {
                fFmpeg.execute (cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler () {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        Log.e ("onStart", "onStart execute");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String message) {
                        Log.e ("onProgress execute", message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String message) {
                        Log.e ("onFailure execute", message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String message) {
                        Log.e ("onSuccess execute", message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        Log.e ("onFinish execute", "onFinish execute");
                    }
                });
            } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
                // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
            }`
```

It shows the following error :

```
`onFailure execute: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
```

Trailing options were found on the commandline.

```
                                                            Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20171212_120337.mp4':
                                                               Metadata:
                                                                 major_brand     : mp42
                                                                 minor_version   : 0
                                                                 compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                                 creation_time   : 2017-12-12 06:33:43
                                                               Duration: 00:00:04.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8552 kb/s
                                                                 Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 7842 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 16.84 fps, 16.67 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                                 Metadata:
                                                                   rotate          : 90
                                                                   creation_time   : 2017-12-12 06:33:43
                                                                   handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                                 Side data:
                                                                   displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
                                                                 Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
                                                                 Metadata:
                                                                   creation_time   : 2017-12-12 06:33:43
                                                                   handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                          **At least one output file must be specified**`
```

Comment: this is the command   String[] cmd = {"-y",
                    "-i",
                    "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20171212_120337.mp4",
                    "-vf",
                    "format=yuv444p",
                    "-codec:v",
                    "drawtext=text='Title of this Video': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=(h/PHI)+th  box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5",
                    "-c:v copy",
                    "outVideo.mp4"
            };

Comment: -y -i  input.mp4 -vf format=yuv444p -codec:v drawtext=text='Title of this Video': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=(h/PHI)+th box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5 -c:v copy outVideo.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Your command is malformed. drawtext is a filter, not a codec, so it needs to be moved to the proper location:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "format=yuv444p,drawtext=text='Title of this Video': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=(h/PHI)+th box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5" outVideo.mp4
```

- It is not possible to use `-c:v copy` when filtering so I removed that.
- I'm not sure why you wanted `format=yuv444p`, but I left it to show how to chain two linear filters together.

Comment: now it is showing this error :                                                                          Unable to find a suitable output format for 'fontcolor=white:'  fontcolor=white:: Invalid argument